# how to change css content attribute of a list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code where I add an automated content (a counter starting from 1) to `div` items within each `li` element. I use css for this : `content:counter(step)` and `counter-increment:step`.

Everything works fine however I want the last element in the list to display a custom text instead of the counter value (which is 5 currently). I tried `content:"MyText"` but did not work. How can I achieve this for the last item in the list?

**Note that** I add the last list item using jquery, and I have to do it this way.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#progressbar').append('<li id="level4" data-levelscore="45" class="done" style="content:\'A\'">Completed</li>');
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
  counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/

#progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 80%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -40%;
  top: 7px;
  z-index: 1;
  /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  /*connector not needed before the first step*/
  content: none;
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/

/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/

#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: #ffb723;
  color: white;
}
#progressbar li.done:before,
#progressbar li.done:after {
  background: #42aacc;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-top: 0.2em; width: 70%; float: left; text-align: left; color: white; ">
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li id="level1" data-levelscore="10" class="done" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="level 1">Level 1</li>
    <li id="level2" data-levelscore="25" class="done" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="level 2">Level 2</li>
    <li id="level3" data-levelscore="35" class="done" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="level 3">Level 3</li>
    <li id="level4" data-levelscore="45" class="done" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="level 4">Level 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just add this rule it did it for me:

```
#progressbar li:last-child:before{
  content: "A";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#progressbar').append('<li id="level4" data-levelscore="45" class="done" style="content:\'A\'">Completed</li>');
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
  counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/

#progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 80%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -40%;
  top: 7px;
  z-index: 1;
  /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  /*connector not needed before the first step*/
  content: none;
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/

/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/

#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: #ffb723;
  color: white;
}
#progressbar li.done:before,
#progressbar li.done:after {
  background: #42aacc;
  color: white;
}

#progressbar li:last-child:before {
 content:"CUSTOM";
 width:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-top: 0.2em; width: 70%; float: left; text-align: left; color: white; ">
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li id="level1" data-levelscore="10" class="done" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="level 1">Level 1</li>
    <li id="level2" data-levelscore="25" class="done" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="level 2">Level 2</li>
    <li id="level3" data-levelscore="35" class="done" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="level 3">Level 3</li>
    <li id="level4" data-levelscore="45" class="done" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="level 4">Level 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Change the added list item (< li >) id to level5, you have duplicated ids, and thats not good.

2) Use this CSS to change the content of that li:

```
li#level5:before {
    content: 'someText';
}
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/g5axowyd/)